# Change bgcolor on toggled tr and on key shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide

I have the following toggle function `filter()` where I display the `childrow` of a table when the `<tr>` parent is being clicked. In this function I've also included a key shortcut, so whenever ALT+A is pressed all the childrows are displayed.

In addition I have another script, `mouseover()`,  where the background color of the parent `tr` is changed to `#2C4367` hover.

**So here's my question:** How can I toggle the background-color of a tr parent whenever I expand (click on) it and back to normal when it is closed. This function should also work on all `tr` parents when the key shortcut is pressed, so the background color of all parent `tr`'s is changed when the shortcut is being pressed.

I hope I made myself clear. Otherwise please say so and I will try to elaborate.

**`Toggle filter() script:`**

```
$(document).ready(function mouseover(){
    $(".parent").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#2C4367");
        $(this).css("color", "#FFFFFF");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#FFFFFF");
        $(this).css("color", "#000000");
    });
});
```

**`Change bgcolor mouseover() script:`**

```
$(document).ready(function filter() {
    $('table.detail').each(function() {
        var $table = $(this);
        $table.find('.parent').click(function() {
            $(this).nextUntil('.parent').toggle(); // must use jQuery 1.4 for nextUntil() method

        }); /// Below is toggle on image
        var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();
        $("img.pushme").toggle(function funcVis() {
            $childRows.show();
        },
        function() { $childRows.hide();
        });
        shortcut.add("Alt+A",function(){ funcVis() }); /// Shortcut functions
        shortcut.add("Alt+N",function(){ expandform() }); /// Shortcut functions
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sparcx/1866jsbo/4/)

```
function toggle(it) {

    if ((it.className == "") || (it.className == "rowactive")) {
        it.className = "rownotactive";
    } else {
        it.className = "rowactive";
    }
}

$(document).ready(function filter() {
    $('table.detail').each(function () {
        var $table = $(this);
        $table.find('.parent').click(function () {

            $(this).toggleClass('rowactive');
            $(this).nextUntil('.parent').toggle();

        }); /// Below is toggle on image

        var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();

        $("img.pushme").toggle(function funcVis() {
            $("tr.parent").addClass('rowactive');
            $childRows.show();

        },

        function () {
            $("tr.parent").removeClass('rowactive');
            $childRows.hide();

        });
        shortcut.add("Alt+N", function () {
            expandform()
        }); /// Shortcut functions
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class that defines the `background-color` change, and apply or remove it with

```
$(target).parent().toggleClass('yourclass');
```

Insert this line wherever the expand is triggered.

Comment: I've tried `toggleClass` but there is a problem with that. If I apply the `toggleClass` for whena `tr` is clicked and for when the hotkey, which triggers the funcVis() functions that expands all  `tr`'s, they interefere with each other.

Say I have five rows of parent `tr`. When I click i.e second and fourth row, they will change background color. But if I then use the hotkey that expands all five rows, the second and fourth row will now change back to normal even though they are expanded.

Comment: Im sorry, but im a bit confused by your explanation. Do you mind creating a quick jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure thing: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sparcx/1866jsbo/1/) 1. Press the image one time and they expand and change color - which they should. 2. Press the image again and they collapse, but stay in color.. 3. Try reloading the page and toggle first row. It changes color as it should. 4. Now try to press the image to expand all rows and you will see the first row's background color toggles - which it shouldn't